# Problem using Powershell to extract a value from a Json structure

Tags: json, powershell

Using Powershell, I get a json snippet returned into my First variable (this always works fine);

```
# Initialise variables...
$nMessage_id = "";
$whatStatusJsonContent = "";
# Function https://abc.googleapis.com/abc/load call here and returns...
$whatStatusJsonContent = '{"message_id":9093813071099257562}'
```

Then I call the convert function into a temp variable like this;

```
$ResponseBody = ConvertFrom-Json $whatStatusJsonContent;
```

which puts the Json into a nice little data structure like this;

```
         message_id
         ----------
9093813071099257562
```

From which I can select the value I want by calling this;

```
$nMessage_id = $ResponseBody.message_id;
```

Usually, this works fine and I get the value into my second variable;

```
$nMessage_id = 9093813071099257562
```

The problem is: Sometimes I get nothing in *$nMessage_id*, even though *$whatStatusJsonContent* is definitely logged as having the Json returned correctly from the function.

My question is: Do I have to *ConvertFrom-Json*, or can I read it raw from the First variable..?

COMBINED SOLUTION: Thanks to @mklement() and @Bernard-Moeskops

```
# Initialise variables...
$nMessage_id = "";
$whatStatusJsonContent = "";
# Function https://abc.googleapis.com/abc/load call here and returns...
$whatStatusJsonContent = '{"message_id":9093813071099257562}'

$ResponseBody = ConvertFrom-Json $whatStatusJsonContent;

if($ResponseBody.message_id){
    # ConvertFrom-Json got the value!
    $nMessage_id = $ResponseBody.message_id
}else{
    # ConvertFrom-Json didn't work!
    $nMessage_id = = ($whatStatusJsonContent -split '[:}]')[1]
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's nothing overtly wrong with your code.

[`ConvertFrom-Json`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.utility/convertfrom-json) should work as expected and return a `[pscustomobject]` instance with a `.message_id` property.

In your example, the `message_id` JSON property value is a *number* that is an integer, for which `ConvertTo-Json` automatically chooses a suitable integer data type as follows: the smallest signed type >= `[int]` (`System.Int32`)<sup>[1]</sup> that can accommodate the value (`[int]` -> `[long]` (`System.Int64`) -> `[decimal]` (`System.Decimal`)); the caveat is that if the value can't even fit into a `[decimal]`, an - inexact - `[double]` is used.<sup>[2]</sup>

With the sample JSON in your question, `[long]` is chosen.

In a follow-up comment you state:

> The routine makes over 1000 calls/hour and for most of them the Json comes back and the `$nMessage_id` is yielded perfectly. Then, suddenly, the `$nMessage_id` is empty, even though the Json is logged as coming back fine. So, somewhere in the `ConvertFrom-Json` or `$ResponseBody.message_id` the value is going missing...

I have no explanation, but if - for whatever reason - `ConvertFrom-Json` is the culprit, you can **try *string manipulation* as a *workaround*** to extract the message ID and see if that helps:

```
$whatStatusJsonContent = '{"message_id":9093813071099257562}'

# Extract the message_id property value as a *string*  
# (which you can cast to a numeric type if/as needed).  
$message_id = ($whatStatusJsonContent -split '[:}]')[1]
```

The above stores a string with content `9093813071099257562` in `$message_id`; note that, as written, the input string must have the exact format as above with respect to whitespace; while it is possible to make the text parsing more robust, not having to worry about format variations is one good reason to use a dedicated parser such as `ConvertFrom-Json`.

---

Another option is to **try a *different* JSON parser** to see if that helps.
[Json.NET](https://www.newtonsoft.com/json) is the preeminent JSON parser in the .NET world (which now underlies the JSON cmdlets in PowerShell *Core*):

```
$whatStatusJsonContent = '{"message_id":9093813071099257562}'

$message_id = [NewtonSoft.Json.Linq.JObject]::Parse($whatStatusJsonContent).message_id.Value
```

Note: Json.NET - like `ConvetFrom-Json` in PowerShell _Core - commendably uses the arbitrary large `[bigint]` type as well once a number is too large to fit into a `[long]`.

Use of the Json.NET assembly has the added advantage of *better performance* than the `ConvertFrom-Json` cmdlet.

In PowerShell *Core*, you can run the above code as-is (the assembly is preloaded); in Windows PowerShell you'll have to download the package via the link above and add the assembly (`NewtonSoft.Json.dll`) to your session with `Add-Type -LiteralPath`.

---

<sup>[1] Curiously, in PowerShell *Core*, as of (at least) v6.2.0, the smallest type chosen is `[long]` (`System.Int64`).</sup>

<sup>[2] More helpfully, PowerShell *Core*, as of (at least) v6.2.0, creates an arbitrarily large `[bigint]` (`System.Numerics.BigInteger`) instance once a value doesn't fit into a `[long]` anymore; that is, the `[decimal]` type is skipped altogether.</sup>

Comment: Thanks, @rangi; I'm glad you found a working solution. It would still be interesting to know the true cause of the problem, i.e., if there's a `ConvertFrom-Json` bug; have you tried the Json.NET alternative, so you don't have to rely on text parsing?

Comment: I will try that when I get a chance, it's a bit trickier because I may not be able to upload a package into the Azure serverless environment. Cheers!

Answer (score 1):

You are going to have to convert it, so that PowerShell can understand it. It will convert from a string to a PSCustomObject. Just check by asking the type of the variable before and after.

```
$ResponseBody.message_id.GetType()
```

If sometimes the output is nothing, you could do something like:

```
if($ResponseBody.message_id){
    $nMessage_id = $ResponseBody.message_id
}else{
    throw "No message id found"
}
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: I highly doubt that that is the problem. I think it actually does not return any data at the times the variable is empty.. What you need to do is use Powershell_ise.exe and make sure to put something like the following in your script. # if(!$ResponseBody.message_id){Write-Host "The Response body is empty"} # Now place a brakepoint (F9) on the Write-Host section. Run the script, and as soon as the body is empty, you will hit the brakepoint. Now the script pauses and you can troubleshoot with the specific call which is empty. Hope this helps and let me know if i need to clarify further.

Comment: The only thing I can imagine is, because of a connection dropping or something, the response is empty every once in a million? times. The ConvertFrom-Json will always work when given valid input. If a certain program is written solid, it does not fail. However, making calls to an API has a lot of dependencies. In your case, it is very hard to troubleshoot. Network-related issues is the obvious to blame. You could try to gather more than just the $ResponseBody.message_id, for instance StatusCode and whenever it is different than e.g. 200 to output the response/error.

Comment: Thanks @Bernard-Moeskops for your help, see combined solution